# Setting the range of acceptable input for a vector

Tags: r, function, vector

Let's say I have a numeric vector that specifies `acceptable` range for an `input` is `1:4`.

In the EXamples below, how can I obtain my `desired_output`?

```
acceptable = 1:4

# EX 1:
input = 0:7

desired_output = 1:4


# EX 2:
input = 6
desired_output = 4
```

Comment: EX1 appears to truncate `input` to the range of `acceptable`, while EX2 appears to change the `input` value. I would expect the second input to return `NA` or produce an error. Can you clarify the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can create a function

```
f1 <- function(inp, accept) {
    out <- intersect(inp, accept)
    if(length(out) == 0) out <- max(accept)
   return(out)
}
```

-testing

```
> input <- 6
> f1(input, acceptable)
[1] 4
> input = 0:7
> f1(input, acceptable)
[1] 1 2 3 4
```